# Allocating memory with calloc for an int pointer

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-ide

Hey guys given the example below in C when operating on a 64bit system as i understand, a pointer is 8 byte. Wouldn't the calloc here allocate too little memory as it takes the sizeof(int) which is 4 bytes? Thing is, this still works. Does it overwrite the memory? Would love some clarity on this.

Bonus question: if i remove the type casting (int*) i sometimes get a warning "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*', does this mean it still works considering the warning?

```
int *ptr;
ptr = (int*)calloc(4, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: The warning "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*'" means you're using a C++ compiler.

Comment: The sizes you hand to `calloc` are to determine the size of the memory region it allocates, not the size of the pointer you and it will point to that region with.  If you're worried about the pointer in the question not having enough bits, what about `calloc(1, sizeof(char))`?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`calloc` is allocating the amount of memory you asked for on the heap. The pointer is allocated by your compiler either in registers or on the stack. In this case, `calloc` is actually allocating enough memory for 4 `int`s on the heap (which on most systems is going to be 16 bytes, but for the arduino uno it would be 8 because the `sizeof(int)` is 2), then storing the pointer to that allocated memory in your register/stack location.

For the bonus question: Arduino uses C++ instead of C, and that means that it uses C++'s stronger type system. `void *` and `int *` are different types, so it's complaining. You should cast the return value of `malloc` when using C++.